# How to recover the colors of the Medium High Contrast look in After Effects?

Tags: color-management, filmic-blender

Do you know a way to recover the colors of MultiExr shots in After effect with a Medium High Contrast look on it? I followed a tutorial that allows me to apply the Filmic LUT but not the look.

Thanks

Comment: can you share some screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. I finally made a curve in AE to recreate the contrast.

Comment: Please share your curve so that others who find your question will be able to find the answer.

Comment: Export Filmic Base Log, and then use a spreadsheet to convert the contrasts to one that works in Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Since EXR has linear colors, I'm pretty sure that you need to use **Linear to sGRB** or **Linear to Gamma 2.2** or **Linear to Gamma 2.4** LUTs

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am not sure about this, I just need the small correction of the Look curves, not the filmic LUT.